# How to stop Flink Job after certain condition is met

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink application with 1 input source, it goes through several maps and sinks back to a kafka source.

Based on some condition, in a single map. I would like to stop the map and all maps in the job in a safe manner.
And stop the job safely.

How do I stop a flink job from within the flink application?

I tried adding a hard failure.
Like accessing a null pointer which would crash the application.

However somestimes only that map would fail and all the others would either go to cancelled (expected) or some just hang (cancelling)

```
 val in_stream = env.addSource(myConsumer).name(topic_in).setParallelism(1)
  .map(x => doSomethingA(x)
  .map(x => doSomethingB(x)
  .map(x => doSomethingC(x) //In this map i want to safely stop the job based on some condition
  .map(x => doSomethingD(x)
  .addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09[String](broker, topic_out, new SimpleStringSchema()))
```

I expect to safely exit the job (all maps cancelled)
How would I go about doing this?